# jpackage jlink sign binary within msi

Tags: windows-installer, digital-signature, signtool, jpackage

with jlink/jpakage i create a msi to install my javafx app but if i sign msi the final binaries installed are not signed at all.
With an ant task and non modular app i know how to do it "create jar>launch4j exe>sign exe> innosetup install exe> sign setup exe" and all works well but with modular jlink and jpackage i can only create msi and sign it but files installed by it (exe, installion files etc) lose signature.

How can i do it? or do i use still an ant task/gradle task without jlink/jpackage?

Comment: I think you'd need to sign the binaries before packaging them into an msi

Comment: i tried but the exe installed by the msi still not signed.

Comment: @JornVernee is right, the binaries have to be signed before being packaged in the msi installer. The signature shouldn't go away, unless the binaries are regenerated when the package is created. Check you build